# How to extract data from xml on ejabberd server?

Tags: ejabberd

I am using custom module to view data of every coming packet on the ejabberd server. My log print on the terminal is given below:

```
18:30:06.370 [info] mod_stanza_ack a presence has been sent coming from: {jid,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<"2923451306214954478930">>,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<"2923451306214954478930">>}
18:30:06.371 [info] mod_stanza_ack a presence has been sent to: {jid,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>}
18:30:06.372 [info] mod_stanza_ack a presence has been sent with the following packet:
 {presence,<<"IaOQN-29">>,unavailable,<<"en">>,{jid,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<"2923451306214954478930">>,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<"2923451306214954478930">>},{jid,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>},undefined,[],undefined,[],#{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,49320,422}}}
```

how can I extract data from xml format using specific tags like:
from first and second line: **jid**.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/processone/xmpp#stanzas

There's plenty of example code in... ejabberd source code :P

Comment: Cannot understand who to use it properly to get a single value from list. I am new on ejabberd.
{jid,
    <<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d">>,
    <<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,
    <<"10613841994037853919914">>,
    <<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d">>,
    <<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,
    <<"10613841994037853919914">>
} I am trying to get a single value like this:
fromId = 67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d

Comment: Instead of From, use: From#jid.user

Comment: Is there any function or library that can give me a string directly like other languages? Because, the way you provided me to get user-id is returning in this format <<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d">>. Does any extra work is required to convert this format into a normal string format?

Comment: That's a string in erlang's binary format. You want a string in erlang's list format, so convert it with: binary_to_list(From#jid.user)