# how to extract data from ejabberd packet?

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to extract data from the packet to send a message to the user from FCM. Before creating json for FCM I try to extract from, to id and body. like this:

```
-behaviour(gen_mod).

%% public methods for this module
-export([start/2, stop/1, mod_options/1, mod_doc/0, depends/2, create_message/1, post_offline_message/3]).

-include("/home/faiqkhan/ejabberd-20.07/lib/fast_xml-1.1.43/include/fxml.hrl").

%% Required by ?INFO_MSG macros
-include("/home/faiqkhan/ejabberd-20.07/lib/ejabberd-20.07/include/logger.hrl").
-include("/home/faiqkhan/ejabberd-20.07/lib/ejabberd-20.07/include/translate.hrl").

start(_Host, _Opt) -> 
    %% post_offline_message("testFrom", "testTo", "testBody"),
    ?INFO_MSG("mod_http_offline loading", []),
    ejabberd_hooks:add(offline_message_hook, _Host, ?MODULE, create_message, 0).

stop (_Host) -> 
    ?INFO_MSG("stopping mod_http_offline", []),
    ejabberd_hooks:delete(offline_message_hook, _Host, ?MODULE, create_message, 0).

create_message({_Action, Msg} = Acc) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("Packet details: ~p", [Msg]),
    From = fxml:get_path_s(xmpp:encode(Msg), [{elem, "from"}, cdata]),
    ?INFO_MSG("PacketsDataType ~p",[From]),
    Acc.

depends(_Host, _Opts) ->
    [].

mod_options(_Host) ->
    [].

mod_doc() ->
    #{desc =>
          ?T("This an example module.")}.
```

In the create_message function, I print the whole message which is working fine but when I try to extract data from Msg it always empty.

> Msg result: Packet details: {message,<<"O1aMy-77">>,normal,<<"en">>,{jid,<<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<"17001580062519808553115">>,<<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<"17001580062519808553115">>},{jid,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>,<<"e5d6d83c-ea77-4d10-aaac-4e0e38899ac2">>,<<"faiqkhan-virtualbox">>,<<>>},[],[{text,<<>>,<<"103020">>}],undefined,[],#{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,49320,393},stanza_id => 1599039505408932}}** and extracted data result is: **PacketsDataType <<>>

Comment: What happened with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499864/how-to-search-registered-user-on-ejabberd-server-from-client-side-using-smack-li and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63524524/how-to-extract-data-from-xml-on-ejabberd-server ? I provided answers to them, with no feedback.

Comment: I up-voted the answer to this question which worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63524524/how-to-extract-data-from-xml-on-ejabberd-server and for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499864/how-to-search-registered-user-on-ejabberd-server-from-client-side-using-smack-li I am now registring the user if the registration of user gives duplicate exception I simply logged-in the user. In the current question, I also tried ```Packet#message.to``` but getting **record message undefined**.

Comment: I successfully extracted the data by changing the packet attribute like this: ```EncodedData = xmpp:encode(Packet) Body = fxml:get_path_s(EncodedData)[{elem, <<"body">>}, cdata]), ?INFO_MSG("PacketsBody ~p",[Body]),``` this works perfectly but when I try to extract **to** id it always return empty data like this **<<>>**. I am extracting to id like this: ```ToS = fxml:get_path_s(EncodedData, [{elem, <<"message">>}, {attr,"to"}]),```

Comment: Done with extracting all the data by using the following code:```{value, To} = fxml:get_tag_attr(<<"to">>, EncodedData),
    {value, From} = fxml:get_tag_attr(<<"from">>, EncodedData),
    Body = fxml:get_path_s(EncodedData, [{elem, <<"body">>}, cdata]),```

Comment: Have you solved with your new investigations? If not solved yet, you can update your original question with the new code, and the new problem.

Comment: Yes, I solved it.